# Импорт библиотеки в android studio

Tags: android

версия студии 0.5.8
пытаюсь добавить либу (https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip)
file -> import module ничего не добавляется
помогите пожалуйста, заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Там на странице описано как подключать.

> Include the library as local library project or add the dependency in your build.gradle.
>
> dependencies {
>     compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
> }

Добавьте это в build.gradle и обновите проект (кнопка gradle update или что-то такое)